# Creating custom layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a layout similar to the image in my android app.I think i can apply the logical through the programming.But i don't have much idea/knowledge on how to create a layout for the same.

Can someone please give some suggestion on how should i approach creating the layout.

[image]

Comment: What specific problem are you facing? If you don't know anything about Android layouts, I would advice you to do some tutorials. And then ask a specific question on this forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First read about [drawing shapes in Android.](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/24/drawing-shapes-in-android/)

Once you figured out how it works, you can define 2 shapes: one with blue background and a rounded black border, and another shape with transparent background and rounded gray border.

Then you set these shapes as background resourses to 2 RelativeLayout's. The stars most probably you'll need to have as jpg images.

Comment: jpg is no way - it kills quality instantly when used with graphinc like this, and also doesn't support transparency

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget32"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/widget33"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:text="TextView"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget34"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
  <TextView
android:id="@+id/widget35"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:text="TextView"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
 <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="4"
    android:stepSize="1.0"
    android:rating="2.0" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

this is just draft of layout. you must add background for it. you can use android shape. also you can add oval png pictures